# Multiple static class member functions all with same arguments and return

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

In C++, let's say that I have the following header file:

```
class Foo {
  static int func0 (int, int);
  static int func1 (int, int);
  static int func2 (int, int);
  static int func3 (int, int);
};
```

Is there anyway to do this via typedefs?

I tried:

```
class Foo {
  typedef int(*func)(int, int);
  static func func1;
  static func func2;
  static func func3;
  static func func4;
};
```

And then in a cpp file

```
int Foo::func1(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

but I get the error:

> Redefinition of func1 as different kind of symbol

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve? I strongly suspect that there is an easy way of achieving what you want, but it depends on what your overall goal is.

Comment: Your problem is probably in the design of your code. Post the real example with comments what the functions should do.

Answer (score 1):

`func1` has been declared as a function pointer, not as a function which you are trying to define it as.

Example use of a function pointer:

```
typedef int (*func_t)(int, int);

int func1(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
int func2(int a, int b) { return a * b; }

funct_t op = func1;
assert(9 == op(4, 5));

op = func2;
assert(20 == op(4, 5));
```

Having said that, I am unsure what your exact intention is.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you want with typedefs, but if you really, really want to do this, you could use the preprocessor.

```
#define MAKE_MY_FUNC(funcname) static int funcname(int, int)

class Foo {
  MAKE_MY_FUNC(func0);
  MAKE_MY_FUNC(func1);
  MAKE_MY_FUNC(func2);
  MAKE_MY_FUNC(func3);
};

#undef MAKE_MY_FUNC  // To make sure that you don't get preprocessor misery afterwards.
```